# Numbers whose reciprocals sum to $1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, fractions, egyptian-fractions

What are all the numbers that can be written as $a_1+a_2+\dots+a_n$, where $a_1,\dots,a_n$ are positive integers such that $\frac{1}{a_1}+\dots+\frac{1}{a_n}=1$? For instance, such numbers include $4=2+2$, $11=2+3+6$, and $16=4+4+4+4$.

Is there a characterization of such numbers? The first few are $1, 4, 9$ and $11$.

Comment: You missed $10=2+4+4$. This is [sequence A125726](https://oeis.org/A125726) in OEIS.

Comment: This is [OEIS sequence A125726](https://oeis.org/A125726). The entry includes two references but not much other information.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These are called [Egyptian numbers](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EgyptianNumber.html). It is known that all numbers greater than $23$ are Egyptian, so you get a characterization by listing a finite list of non-Egyptian numbers.

Comment: See http://oeis.org/A028229.